# Projective dimension of an ideal generated by a regular sequence

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring with $1$ and $I$ be an ideal of $R$ generated by an $R$-sequence of length $n$. I want a simple (if any) proof that the projective dimension of $I$ is $n-1$.

I think the usual s.e.s. $$0→I→R→R/I→0$$ may work.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried to prove it by induction?

For $n=1$ we have a short exact sequence $$0\to R\stackrel{x\cdot}\to R\to R/(x)\to 0,$$ so $\operatorname{pd}_RR/(x)\le 1$. It's easily seen that $\operatorname{pd}_RR/(x)\ne0$ (why?), so $\operatorname{pd}_RR/(x)=1$.

For $n>1$ let's start by setting $R^*=R/(x_1)$. Since $x_2^*,\dots,x_n^*$ is an $R^*$-sequence of length $n-1$, by the induction hypothesis we get $\operatorname{pd}_{R^*}R^*/(x_2^*,\dots,x_n^*)=n-1$, that is, $\operatorname{pd}_{R^*}R/(x_1,\dots,x_n)=n-1$. By [the first change of rings theorem](http://therisingsea.org/notes/Dimensions.pdf) we get $\operatorname{pd}_{R}R/(x_1,\dots,x_n)=1+\operatorname{pd}_{R^*}R/(x_1,\dots,x_n)=1+n-1=n$.

Comment: I think Ext functor might help to see why $R/(x)$ is not projective so that its projective dimension is not zero. But I could not go through. May you elucidate the "why"? Thanks!

Comment: @karparvar If $pd(R/(x))=0$ then $R/(x)$ is projective, so $(x)$ is a drect summand of $R$, that is, $(x)$ is generated by an idempotent, a contradiction with $x$ non-zero divisor.