# Example of a finitely generated torsion-free module of projective dimension 2

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Is there a module which is finitely generated, torsion-free, and of projective dimension 2 at the same time? I was just wondering if such an example exists...

Answer (score 0):

In an integral domain $R$, an ideal is a torsion-free $R$-module, and if it is generated by a regular sequence of length $r$, it has projective dimension $r-1$. So take, for instance, $R=K[X,Y,Z]$ ($K$ a field) and consider the ideal $I=(X, Y, Z)$.

Comment: "*integral domain*" is superfluous; see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1307050/projective-dimension-of-an-ideal-generated-by-a-regular-sequence).

Comment: @user26857: I know that, but ‘Integral domain’ is for the requirement  the modyule be torsion-free. I should have mentioned that.