# Projective dimension and number of generators of an ideal

Tags: polynomials, commutative-algebra

Let $R = k[x_1 , \ldots , x_n]$ be the polynomial ring with $n$ variables where $k$ is a field. Let $I = \langle f_1, \ldots , f_t \rangle$ be an ideal of $R$ with $t$ generators. By Hilbert Syzygy Theorem, we know that $\text{pdim } I \leq n$.

Is there a relation between $t$ and $\text{pdim } I$? Can we say that $\text{pdim } I \leq t$? or can we say that $\text{pdim } R/I \leq t$?

Comment: Second: there exists three generated ideals $I$ with $\mathrm{pd}(R/I)=4$. On the other side, the property holds for two-generated ideals, that is, in this case $\mathrm{pd}(R/I)=2$.

Comment: @user26857 Thanks for the answer. Could you please give me an example of an ideal $I$ with three generators such that $\text{pd} (R/I) = 4$?

Comment: $R=K[X,Y,Z,T]$ and $I=(X^2,Y^2,XZ+YT)$.

Comment: @user26857 Why does the property hold for two-generated ideals?

Comment: You may assume that the generators of a two-generated ideal are coprime, and in this case they form an $R$-sequence. Then see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1307050/projective-dimension-of-an-ideal-generated-by-a-regular-sequence).

Comment: @user26857 Thanks for the answer and reference. I'm wondering the case that the two generators of the ideal $I$ are not coprime. In this case, can I say that $\text{pd } R/I \leq 2$? or is there any example for which $\text{pd } R/I > 2$?

Comment: If the generators are not coprime, then the ideal they generate is isomorphic (as $R$-module) with an ideal whose generators are coprime. That's why I said "you may assume that the generators of a two-generated ideal are coprime".

Comment: @user26857 If $I = \langle f,g \rangle$ where $f = f_1 r$ and $g = g_1 r$ such that $f_1 , g_1 , r \in R$ and $f_1 , g_1$ coprime, then we can say that $I = \langle f,g \rangle \simeq \langle f_1,g_1 \rangle$ with the isomorphism $\alpha : \langle f_1,g_1 \rangle \to \langle f,g \rangle$ which sends $a \in \langle f_1,g_1 \rangle$ to $ra \in \langle f,g \rangle$. Right?

Comment: Right..${}{}{}$